how to enlarge a plot within a display window
I'm trying to make a 3Dplot fill a display window since matplotlib leaves a lot of blank space within the window by default and I need the plot to be big since it has a lot of small details. I've tried a number of recipes like
px = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1800*px, 1200*px))

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [32,24]

or even  matplotlib how to set plot size (with dpi), not figure size
but they just make the window size bigger (and the plot accordingly) leaving a lot of blank space within. I'd rather like to fill the inner space of the window with the plot.

Adding
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'}, facecolor='lightgray')
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, left=-0.15, top=1, right=0.56)
ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), np.diag([2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1]))

I get a large image, right what I was looking for, but cutoff in the middle by a grey blank space


What IDE and which backend are you using? I know one answer for jupyter and using qt backend

Does this answer your question? How to maximize a plt.show() window

I have tried some and only one worked, but it's always the size of the window that gets maximized, not the size of the plot within the window. I've attached the plot in the question (see above) to show how much void space there is around the plot; that's what I would like to avoid. I'll keep trying the other proposed solutions tomorrow. My backend seems to be wxt or win and my IDE is the cmd prompt, that is, the simplest one.

Now I see, you want to increase the size of the plotting window. What about here

Try fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1800*px, 1200*px), layout="constrained")

@Tino D your link provides good ideas, I have tried some and they work well. However, rather than scaling the x, y and z-axis, I would need to scale the horizontal and vertical size of the plot (ideally so as to fill the display window almost entirely). Any ideas?

@gboffi (for other readers) where you say fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1800*px, 1200*px), layout="constrained") it must be preceded by px = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']

I think that what you want is a constrained layout.
It is possible to have no borders at all, but the Axes3D won't fill the Figure anyway. With a "regular" Axes you can play with the aspect ratio and fill the figure but not with an Axes3D, asfaict.
Playing with figsize you can fill the figure but you'll miss the labels on z axis.
I still advise the constrained layout approach, but the feet is yours :-)




import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'}, facecolor='lightgray')
fig1.suptitle('Smaller')

fig2, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'}, facecolor='lightgray', layout='constrained')
fig2.suptitle('Bigger')

fig3, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'}, facecolor='lightgray')
fig3.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, left=0, top=1, right=1)
fig3.suptitle('Biggest')

fig4, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'}, facecolor='lightgray', figsize=(6,6))
fig4.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, left=0, top=1, right=1)
fig4.suptitle('Biggest, Square Figure')

plt.show()


It's certainly better, but it could even be better. I need to scale the horizontal & vertical size of the plot to fit the whole display window. For that, I might need to set the origin of the plot too (something like set_origin (0,0) where (0,0) are some kind of "display-window coordinates" )

That's certainly much better ! Sorry that I hadn't seen the update before. I have tried left = -0.3 and right = 1.3 to stretch it out horizontally but it didn't work :) As far as I understand from what you say, it's not possible to place the origin at the very left for a 3D plot, and even less to then stretch it out in the horizontal direction, right ?

@user24353751 Matplotlib 100% always does what you want, sometimes. ;-)    ① If you play with figsize=(x,y) and specify an y/x ratio that matches the aspect of the Axes, you're closer to what you want ② Probably if you use subplots_adjust(..., right=0.8) you can move the Axes off the centre. PS 0.8 just to say, if it works at all, you have to experiment.

with fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection':'3d'}, facecolor='lightgray'), fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, left=-0.15, top=1, right=0.56) and ax.get_proj = lambda: np.dot(Axes3D.get_proj(ax), np.diag([2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1])) I've gotten a big plot, right what I was looking for, but cutoff in the middle (see picture above). I've tried figsize=(x,y) too with different x & y values but it does nothing (maybe it's only for 2D)

@user24353751 I added an example of changing figsize that does everything.

I appreciate your efforts, @gboffi, but unfortunately figsize (that indeed works in 3D too but not outside plt.subplots parenthesis) affects only the size of the display window, not the size of the plot within the window. The issue here is to remove the light gray border around the canvas widget, for a 3D plot: this way, there will be (hopefully!) no cutoff area on the right, anymore (unlike in the picture above) and thus, that area also will be able to be accessed by the plot (which in my case I would like to be as rectangular as my screen). I'll search around...

I've tried plt.savefig('image.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0) and others and no way. I'll try to reformulate my question in another post including my script since the topic now is to have the whole figure plotted and not cutoff in the middle where the gray border starts.

Could you, @gboffi, stretch out your figure along the horizontal direction ? (so as to have a rectangular, not square, frame). I think there it is the problem. For example figsize=(6,4) will still render a square never bigger than the vertical side of the display window

@user24353751 I feel like you're losing your time chasing this chimera of yours. I still advise you to use constrained layout and let Matplotlib figure out the gory details.  Your time is yours, I've helped you as much as possible but please, now let me alone, thank you.
